# How to limit maximum file size limit in rtMedia 3.7 wordpress plugin?

Tags: buddypress

I'm developing wordpress/buddypress website and I'm using rtMedia 3.7 plugin for photo and album management.

Currently, users can not upload photos with size more than 3MB because I put maximum file size limit to 3MB in php and nginx configuration.

Problem is when user tries to upload 3+MB photo, rtMedia upload UI does not any errors or warnings, but just ignores the upload. (Which seems to be caused by the php and nginx settings)

I want to show nice and friendly error message to the user so that they will know they can't upload pictures more than 3MB.

Here's the rtMedia plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-media/changelog/

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Once, check by updating the plugin to its latest version ( 3.8.11 ), you will be able to see the message with the Max File Size Limit.
Check this link : http://goo.gl/PSBQmG